# Using eval to create datestamp

Tags: python

Trying to get eval to work on a dictionary that comprises a datetime field. I'm attempting to do the following:

```
from datetime import datetime as datetime
print(eval("{'datestamp': datetime.today()}", {}, {}))
```

gives the following:

```
NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined'
```

I want to return a string with a date computed from the datetime function. How do I do this?

Comment: Those extra `{}`s you're passing to `eval` -- one of them is where you'd want to pass in `{"datetime": datetime}` to make it available. (For that matter, why are you passing optional arguments if you don't know what they're for?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the copy of `datetime` you imported as a global, rather than telling `eval` to pass empty sets of both locals and globals, when you want that copy of `datetime` to be accessible within the eval'd code:

```
from datetime import datetime
print(eval("{'datestamp': datetime.today()}", {'datetime': datetime}))
```

Alternately, you can avoid depending on the `import` at all by using `__import__` to pull the module in from within the eval'd string:

```
print(eval("{'datestamp': __import__('datetime').datetime.today()}", {}, {}))
```

...or you can just stop overriding the set of variables exposed to the `eval`:

```
from datetime import datetime
print(eval("{'datestamp': datetime.today()}"))
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't expecting to have to do this, i.e. that datetime would be seen as a function, rather than needing to be passed in. But makes sense.

Comment: Functions and variables share the same namespace in Python. In the LISP world, it would be a LISP-1 (one unified namespace), not a LISP-2 (separate namespaces for functions vs variables).